# JSXGraph: withLines option / setAttribute

Tags: jsxgraph

I would like to draw a polygon without its borders.
This works if I add the option `{withLines: false}` or `{borders:{visible:false}}` in the `create(...)` call.
However, if I omit the option in create and want to change it later using `setAttribute(...)`, the lines are still visible.

This is demonstrated in the following code (http://jsfiddle.net/1teoLz7p):

```
var board = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard('box', {
        boundingbox: [-5,5,5,-5], 
        keepaspectratio: true, 
    });

var ABC = [board.create('point',[0,0]),
    board.create('point',[1,3]),
    board.create('point',[3,2])];

var poly1=board.create('polygon', ABC, {withLines:false});

var DEF = [board.create('point',[-1,0]),
    board.create('point',[-2,3]),
    board.create('point',[-4,2])];

var poly2=board.create('polygon', DEF);
poly2.setAttribute({withLines:false}); // doesnt work
```

The first, right triangle is shown as expected,
but in the second, left triangle the lines are visible.

How to change this option **after** the create call??

Answer (score 0):

You are right, it is not possible to make the lines invisible by calling just `polygon.setAttribute()`. The reason is that `setAttribute` is not yet able to subobjects like in `{borders {visible: false}}` and that also the other approach - setting `withLines:false` - fails because the attribute `withLines` is not dynamic. It mainly prevents creation of the lines for efficiency reasons during construction of the polygon.

We will discuss if we enable these two issues in a future version. 
For the time being, the way to set the lines invisible is the following:

```
 var ABC = [[0,0], [1,3], [3,2]];
 var poly1=board.create('polygon', ABC, {withLines:false});
 var DEF = [[-1,0], [-2,3], [-4,2]];
 var poly2=board.create('polygon', DEF);

 var i;
 for (i = 0; i < poly2.borders.length; i++) {
     poly2.borders[i].setAttribute({visible: false});
 }
```